# dataWithContentsOfURL and HTTP 302 redirects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, http-status-code-302

How does `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` deal with 302 redirects?

I am requesting an MP3 file from a server by passing the URL of a PHP page which will check the user-agent and redirect to the MP3 file on a different server.

Comment: Have you even tried it for yourself?

Comment: @Joe, no I haven't because the server-side of this isn't live yet, and I don't want to waste time going down a path that won't work. I just thought someone else might have tried this before and found that it failed and could share their experience.

Comment: Well I am sure it works fine, but you can be sure by creating a redirect URL and calling it. Try http://goo.gl for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` in a real app. It makes a synchronous network connection and your app will be killed by the OS if that doesn't finish quickly enough.

Stick to `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` or use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`.

Comment: I ended up using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`. I've discovered multi-threading now. For the record, `NSURLConnection` does handle 302s properly.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. +dataWithContentsOfURL: can also be used in another thread in a "real app"

Comment: This is incorrect. `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` can be used in a separate thread, where it would be 100% safe

Answer (score 1):

Write your `loadImageInBackground` function that contains `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`
and run it in a background thread, like this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:nil];
```

This will not make synchronous network connection (hence will not freeze the UI).